# Flag remaining matches in Excel list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table structured as follows:

```
A   B      
   Sam     
   Mike    
X  Sam     
   Sam
```

I need to calculate column C to "X" for every person who had at least one "X" in column A.

```
A   B      C
   Sam     X
   Mike    
X  Sam     X
   Sam     X
```

Conceptually, I would do this using a vlookup formula:

```
C2 = VLOOKUP(B2,"list of names having an "X" in column A", 1,false)
```

...but I don't know how to provide the second element of the lookup. I could build the list manually on a separate sheet, but I want this to be automatic, so as soon as I enter an "X" in column A, "X"s are filled into column C.

Thanks for any advice or ideas!

Comment: realized I didn't complete the formula. It needs to include an IF statement to test if VLOOKUP returned a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes in `C2`. Drag down as needed

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A, "X", B:B, B2) > 0, "X", "")
```